# Why so % does not work when vimrc changes with another editor?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim, vim-windows

- I opened a file in Vim.
- Then opened `vimrc` file with another editor (VsCode) and made some changes.

I would like those changes to be reflected in my Vim session.

- I tried `:so %` but it didn't work correctly.

Why?

How to have the changes in `vimrc` reflected in Vim without restarting Vim?

Comment: It should but depending how your `vimrc` is written re-running is not the same as running. Could you give an example? Could you come with a minimal `vimrc` that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: It depends entirely on the changes made, too. Best is to restart vim.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It was a large file, but I think I needed `set autoread` because `set nu ` did not work in that file. Can you mention some changes that will not appear immediately?

Comment: The options (e.g. `autoread`, `number`) should work fine. What is more tricky is the `autocmd` that depending how they are configured pileup instead of being replaced (`augroup` and `!` flag can be used to control that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:so %`, short for `:source %`, is:

- the `:help :source` command, which is used to "source" vimscript files,
- `%`, which is a shortcut for "the current file".

Therefore, it means "source the current file" or, at a lower level, "execute all the Ex commands from the current file".

If the current file is not a vimscript file, say you opened a `.yaml` file, then "source the current file" is a pointless thing to ask Vim to do because it is very unlikely to contain any vimscript.

From Vim, the proper way to source your `vimrc` is to use the `$MYVIMRC` environment variable (that is only set **IN** Vim):

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

NOTE: As hinted in the comments, not everything you can put in your `vimrc` can be expected to have an immediate effect upon sourcing and settings can come from other places than your `vimrc` anyway, so the command above is *not* a silver bullet. Starting a new session is a much better solution.

NOTE: Editing your `vimrc` in a different editor makes no sense. Doing it in Vim gives you proper syntax highlighting, completion, and direct access to the documentation via `:help K`. And FWIW, it also allows you to do things like `:w|so %` while you are editing your `vimrc`.